# How can I retrieve the column/field names of a table?

Tags: r, rodbc

Using `RODBC`, how can I run a query to return just the column/field names of a given table?

The tables in question are immense (the smallest is approximately >750,000 records across 150 columns/fields) so pulling the tables in each time I want the column/field names is not a sensible solution.

The return I am looking for from this would be similar those returned from the `DESCRIBE` function in SQL when used to describe a table.

Can this be done?

Comment: Is [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/RODBC/man/sqlColumns.html) what you are looking for??

Comment: I had looked at this before but was hoping for a simpler return result (i.e. not a `list` but rather just a vector of names).

I can easily access it by pulling out the `COLUMN_NAME` array, of course, but was looking for something that *only* returns columns names without anything else, like `DESCRIBE` might return in SQL.

Comment: Probably not what you want, but `DBI::dbListFields` returns just a vector of names (`DBI` is generally not used with `RODBC`, though there is `RODBCDBI` ...). I don't know why extracting `COLUMN_NAME` from a list is so onerous, though, what's your rationale for attempting to reinvent that wheel when the `RODBC` package provides a quick and featureful function for it?

Answer (score 0):

con <- odbcConnect("yourdatabase", username, password)

out <- sqlQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM yourschema.yourtable", max=2)

colnames(out)

will return the first 2 rows and column names as object out for your table called "yourtable" in the schema "yourschema" from the database connected to through RODBC